# Requirements for Successful SSL Communication

Tags: c++, ssl, client-server, thrift

I'm using thrift to write a C++ client which will call securely to the server (which is not written by me) written in java (code generated for both server and client using same thrift files). I'm a newbie in SSL communication. For the java server side, I imported the public key certificate of client to the server truststore (server-truststore.jks) to verify the client authenticity. I exported the public certificate from the server side keystore (server.jks) and used it in the client side to authenticate the server key certificate during the SSL handshake. If I list down what I did for the SSL communication:

Server Side (java):

1. exported the client's public key certificate to the server's truststore

Cleint Side (C++):

1. Loaded the server's public certificate which was exported from the server's keystore
2. separately loaded the client's public key and private key (This is because I can't directly use a java key store since the client is written in c++)

All the certificates used are self signed.

So far I have been unsuccessful and got the following error continuously:

```
SSL_connect: certificate verify failed
```

I have two questions:

1. Is the approach I used for SSL communication correct? If not, what is the correct one?
2. Any possible reasons for this error?

Thank you.

Comment: What library/api you using on c++ side fro working with SSL?

Comment: Also, certificate verification fails because he is self signed. Disable verification if you don't worry about validity.

Comment: @gureedo: thanks for the answer. I disabled verification as a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can verify the key invoking directly: openssl s_client -connect serverIP:Port .
If you can is problem of your code, and for that we will need more details about it.
If not... your are not using the cert. the server is sending you, or something is wrong with the certificate.